# File existense check fails with both stat and win_stat

Tags: ansible

This is the code I am trying to run:

```yaml
  tasks:  

   - name: Check that the Temp.txt exists
     win_stat: 
       path:  'E:\\tarfiles\\Temp.txt'  
       register: stat_file

   - name: Create Temp.txt file if ABC.txt exists 
     win_file:
       path: 'E:\\tarfiles\\Temp.txt'
       state: touch
       when: stat_file.stat.exists == True
```

And this is the error I get:

> fatal: [wqlkxccvna01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (win_stat) module: register. Supported parameters include: path, checksum_algorithm, get_checksum, follow, dest, name"}
>
> fatal: [ps-xcc-vna9d06]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (win_stat) module: register. Supported parameters include: path, checksum_algorithm, get_checksum, follow, dest, name"}

Comment: As very explicitely reported in your error mesage, `register` is not a supported parameter for the `(win_)stat` **module**. This is a **task** parameter and you want to indent it one level below (at the same level as the module name). Once your fix that, you will get the exact same error on the next task since `when` suffers from the same problem there. I suggest you [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and spend some time on the [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks)

Answer (score 0):

The spacing of the `register:` and the `when:` is wrong, they should be aligned with the modules `win_stat` and `win_file`.

```yaml
tasks:

  - name: Check that the Temp.txt exists
    win_stat: 
      path:  'E:\\tarfiles\\Temp.txt'  
    register: stat_file

  - name: Create Temp.txt file if ABC.txt exists 
    win_file:
      path: 'E:\\tarfiles\\Temp.txt'
      state: touch
    when: stat_file.stat.exists
```

Be extra careful with spacing in `yaml`.
(btw you don't need the `== True`)